# How do I get a pixel color from an imageView using Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, colors, get, imageview, pixel

I'm trying to get the color of a pixel from my imageView by hovering over it, but my application keeps crashing.

Ive tried using code from stackoverflow threads but most of them are old and outdated and some just didn't work for me.
Tried using Canvas also but it also didn't work.

my code is:

```java
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private fun getPixelInfo() {
        val pixelInfoText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.pixelInfoText)
        val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
        imageView.bringToFront()

        imageView.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
            val x = event.x.toInt()
            val y = event.y.toInt()

            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                pixelInfoText.text = "$x $y"
            }

            true
        }
```

My application keeps crashing,

but it should set the textView text to be like
**"X: 250 Y: 500 COLOR: #F8AC4D"**

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to do it:

```java
val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(layout.width, layout.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
layout.draw(canvas)
val color = bitmap.getPixel(x, y)
```